# ListBox Item Width

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

I have a radlistbox and the items are being inserted programmatically, how do I expand the width of an item so multiple items won't show on a single line as they are showing as of now.

currently items are being inserted to listbox in c# like :

```
rlbAssigned.Items.Add(new RadListBoxItem(rlbAvailable.Items[rlbAvailable.SelectedIndex].Text, rlbAvailable.Items[rlbAvailable.SelectedIndex].Value));
```

and the listbox is declared as:

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="rlbAvailable" runat="server" Height="320px" Width="200px">                                         </telerik:RadListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used radlistbox but seeing your other solution, looks like it acts like a normal list item.

If you only want one of them showig per line. display block should do the trick.

```
.RadListBox ul li       
    { 
      display:block;    
    }
```

Comment: nice solution, but the problem is if the item is empty or the text size is smaller than desired text within items then the second item also show on the same line, if we set the width than no matter what the text size is item will only display on 1 line either empty or full or more if the size is more than 170px.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out since it has Ul and li I resolved it using css like so:

```
 .RadListBox ul li       
    { 
      float: left !important;      
      width: 170px;
    }
```

I would be glad if someone comes up with a another solution.